# Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension of hypergraph, given bound on number of hyperedges

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, graph-theory, hypergeometric-distribution, vc-dimension

in studying now about *Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension*, and there is one question that I not able to solve.

Let $\textrm{(X , R)}$ be a range space so that any hypergraph $\textrm{(V, F)}$ in it satisfies ${|F| \leq
A|V|^B}, $ where $A \in R+$ and ${B \in N+}$ do not depend on $\textrm{|V |}$. Show that $\textrm{Vapnik-Chervonenkis-dimension(X, R)} \leq
10B \log B + \log A. $

as I understand there is bound on number of hyperedges, and probably I can use it to calculate the *Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension*. this is my following idea, given number of $\textrm{|F|}, $the largest set that can be shattered is $\log |F|,$ and $\log |F|$ is the maximum dimension.

Hence $\textrm{Vapnik-Chervonenkis-dimension(X , R)} \leq \log |F| \leq \log |F| \leq \log A|V|^B \leq \log A + B\log |V|.$ But I can't continue from here; I think my solution is wrong, not able not understand how to get this result : $\textrm{Vapnik-Chervonenkis-dimension(X , R)} \leq
10B \log B + \log A. $

Comment: Could you please edit your typesetting to make them more legible? For instance use `textrm` and `\log`.

Comment: sorry for that, yes done.